# Make [samples] synonym of [sample]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request, tags

I would like to propose tag synonym: [samples](/questions/tagged/samples) should be synonym to [sample](/questions/tagged/sample).
I do not have enough reputation to make this proposal myself - so if you read it and have enough reputation, please help me pull this off!

Comment: @hims056 thanks for the tags edit - I always find them confusing here at meta.

Comment: Don't add "Thanks" see: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/187824)

Comment: @hims056 I am familiar with that discussion. Unfortunatly, the [answer I upvoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2965/202617) is not too popular. Personally, I think some **very brief and compact** courtasy is in place as long as it does not clutter the posts. So, thank you again for the edit and for leaving my "thanks" and respecting my opinion on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [ongoing effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135985/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags) to clean up all the pluralized/hyphenated duplicates of tags, as these can't be created any more.

However I'm not sure that *either* tag is needed - we already have [sampling](/questions/tagged/sampling) for statistical-type questions, and any other use of 'sample' doesn't seem like a good tag IMO (e.g. 'code sample').

Perhaps both could/should be removed?